# How to use content_for in kemal slang

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

`content_for` does not work for me. I use Kemal and Slang. Here code:

layout.slang

```
== yield_content "js_css"
```

index.slang

```
- content_for "js_css" do
  javascript:
    window.allowDigits = function(evt) {
      alert("msa7");
    }
```

In output HTML I do not see `alert("msa7")`. 
What wrong with my code?

Comment: Look like issue here https://github.com/kemalcr/kemal/blob/master/src/kemal/helpers/macros.cr#L54. Found in debug `"__content_filename__ src/views/session/index.slang"
"__caller_filename__ /app/src/controllers/session.cr"`

Answer (score 1):

Found workaround by call `content_for` with file name, like this `content_for "js_css", "src/views/session/index.slang"`. Now it works:

index.slang

```
- content_for "js_css", "src/views/session/index.slang" do
  javascript:
    window.allowDigits = function(evt) {
      alert("msa7");
    }
```

Comment: Kemal's `content_for` and `yield_content` don't work properly and they are likely going to be removed (see https://github.com/kemalcr/kemal/issues/467). They should be implemented by Kilt or slang.